# Serving S3 on a EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

We've got a bunch of static assets on S3 that we'd like to securely serve.

Due to the fact that we can't use custom domain names and SSL certificates, and wanting to integrate with our existing auth solutions, we want to try serving the S3 content via a real webserver on EC2.

I found this: http://www.cyberkan.com/how-to-mount-s3-over-ec2-linux/ that shows how to mount S3 as a volume.

Anyone tried serving a S3 bucket via s3fs over Apache or nginx on EC2? Is this a viable strategy in terms of performance and reliability?

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been mixed. S3 is not a block device. Many application access the file system assuming that it is a block device. When you are trying to access a file on an s3fs mount, results can be unpredictable.

S3 does have SSL support, you just need to use their domain. You can provide access to private files via signed urls. Which will be valid to the user for a certian period of time.

Answer (score -2):

You could secure the content by leaving it on S3 and then edit the Bucket Policy on S3 to only allow access to your content when the user clicks a link from your server. So for example, if your content management system (which I assume implements some form of authentication) is at www.example.com, then in S3, go to your bucket's "Properties" and in the "Permissions" area click "Add Bucket Policy".

For example, you could restrict access to a specific HTTP referer using this code:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "aws:Referer":[
            "http://www.example.com/*",
            "http://example.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: this example is from [the S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html)

I've used this approach successfully. Even if someone views the page source and tries to go directly to the S3 bucket source, they will get an "access denied". Only when they are authenticated to www.example.com and click the link to view or download your content from within that authenticated browser session are the able to access the files.

Comment: The HTTP REFERER Header is sent by the user's browser. This is trivial to spoof. This approach is not secure.